# Back button in a referenced storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a view controller and there are a button that leave me at other story board

[image]

and other sotryboard with a navigation controller

[image]

I need a back button on this second storyboard to return to first, how I can do this ?

[image]

Comment: make first controller root controller, and embed it in navigatoin controller.No need of any other navigation controllers.A stack will be maintained for all your controllers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps to achieve, that you want:

1. In your main (first) storyboard, connect a button with a storyboard reference using push segue.

[image]

2. Storyboard Reference: Select storyboard reference of second (other) storyboard and assign any value to reference id like 'SecondStoryboardVC'

[image]

3. In your second storyboard view controller, assign the same value (like SecondStoryboardVC) to viewcontroller's storyboard id.

[image]

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the second NavigationController and automatically should be appear the back button.